# Is the definite article needed here?

Tags: definite-article

I'm trying to improve by ability to recognize instances when the inclusion of the word 'that', prepositions, definite articles, etc. are technically right, but unnecessary.

Do I need to use 'the' in this sentence or is it okay without it?

> *The cameraman focuses his equipment on Mr. Don, but he is saved by **the** arrival of authorities.*

or

> *The cameraman focuses his equipment on Mr. Don, but he is saved by arrival of authorities.*

The second sounded odd to me at first, but then I considered that this sentence makes sense.

> *The cameraman focuses his equipment on Mr. Don, but he is saved by anger.*

So "saved + by + some other noun" sometimes works.....is the article always needed?

Comment: The second sentence, lacking the definite article, is unidiomatic and is likely to put off native speakers. For an analysis of why, I can't recommend highly enough the experts over on our sister site, [ELL.se]. You should ask there.

Comment: This is a good question for ELL StackExchange.

Comment: The third sentence sounds very strange. Saved by anger?

Comment: I know. It was a random noun used to show that there are situations where nouns sound fine without the 'the'. In the proper textbook of a book, 'saved by anger' wouldn't sound strange anymore. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I think *the* is more appropriate here because you're talking about a specific instance of "arrival", not "arrival (of any authorities)" in general.

Answer (score -1):

We could rephrase the second part of the first sentence according to the pattern *[saved + by + some other noun]*:

He is saved by **the event** 
and **this event** actually is **the arrival of authorities.**

So using the definite article seems to be more appropriate for specifying ***that special event*** due to he was saved ***this time***.

A counter-example of using the same pattern without any article could be:

He was saved **by God’s grace.**

The latter is a proper noun, so it requires no article.